# History of interpolation methods - Newton

Tags: math-history, interpolation

I'm interested in reading more about how Newton developed his method of interpolation and also the proofs he developed to this topic. Can anyone recommend me some resources where I can read about this topic? I'm apologising in advance if this question is not well suited for this platform!

Comment: This question might be better suited at “history of math and science stackexchange”.

Comment: @AdamRubinson thanks, I will migrate my question.

Comment: @AdamRubinson do you maybe have any resources, it seems that no-one answers my question on the other forum...

Comment: No I don’t know anything about the history. Have you tried searching on google and wikipedia?

Comment: @AdamRubinson of course